# Como quebrar a linha no prompt do VisuAlg?

Tags: visualg, portugol

Minha saída:

> Nome: Fulano de TalIdade: tantos anos

Como quebrar a linha no *prompt* do VisuAlg?

Para ficar assim:

> Nome: Fulano de Tal
>
> Idade: Tantos Anos

Comment: Poderia passa o link para baixar esse visual log

Comment: http://www.guanabara.info/2007/09/visualg-v25/

Comment: Se era Visual Alg, porque escreveu Visual Log na pergunta?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para quebrar a linha em uma saida de texto utilize a função [escreval()](http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem2.htm#escreval). A lista completa das funções, operadores e demais referências pode encontrar [nesse link](http://eletrica.ufpr.br/~rogerio/visualg/Help/refer.htm)

```
algoritmo "quebra_de_linha"
var
   idade : inteiro
   nome : caractere

inicio
      escreval("Informe o nome")
      leia(nome)

      escreval("Informe a idade")
      leia(idade)

      escreva("")
      escreva("")

      escreval("nome: " + nome)
      escreval("idade: ", idade)

fimalgoritmo
```

saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ola agradeço pela sua ajuda me ajudo muito vlw

Answer (score -1):

simples

```
var
nome:caracter
idade:inteiro

inicio
escreva("seu nome é: ")
leia(nome)
escreval(" ")
escreva("sua idade é: ")
leia(idade)
escreval(" ")

fimalgoritmo
```